# The paste command in phpMyAdmin has disappeared

Tags: phpmyadmin

I upgraded to phpmyadmin 4.4.14, and am now unable to right click to a paste command in the Run SQL window.  The menu that I do get is the common browser right-click menu, (back, reload, save as...).  How else can I verify my PHP SQL statements?

Comment: What was your previous phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: No idea, it was old, like 3.2?

Comment: Please open an issue on https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues

Answer (score 0):

The issue was opened and the answer is given here: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11453